# Change match highlights on CmdlineLeave

Tags: autocmd, highlight, cmdline

Vim uses two different highlight groups for matching patterns while searching in the command-line with `/` or `:substitute` for example.

- The `incsearch` group for the match under the cursor
- The `search` group for the others

When the command-line is left, the match under the cursor is set back to the `search` group. I would like it to remain as it is while in command-line.

I actually wrote a function which changes the group of the match under the cursor. I mapped it to <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>N</kbd>. It also applies a different highlight for the first and last match.

```
" highlight current search and first/last search differently
function! HLCurrent() abort
    if exists("currmatch")
        call matchdelete(currmatch)
    endif
    " only on cursor
    let patt = '\c\%#'.@/
    " check prev and next match
    let prevmatch = search(@/, 'bWn')
    let nextmatch = search(@/, 'Wn')
    " if on first or last match
    if prevmatch == 0 || nextmatch == 0
        let currmatch = matchadd('EdgeSearch', patt, 101)
    else
        let currmatch = matchadd('IncSearch', patt, 101)
    endif
    redraw
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> n n:call HLCurrent()<cr>
nnoremap <silent> N N:call HLCurrent()<cr>
```

It works well, but I still have the problem of the group being changed when leaving the command-line window.

Using my function, I expected this `autocmd` to do the trick, but it does not work as expected:

```
augroup HLCurrentRightNow
    au!
    au CmdlineLeave,CmdwinLeave * call clearmatches() | call HLCurrent()
augroup end
```

So, what would be a way to apply my function when exiting the command-line?